# Upgrade into 64 bit Windows first or update the BIOS first?

Tags: windows, uefi, updates

There was this "Black Screen with Caret" issue and I couldn't boot into Windows, the UEFI firmware settings, or a bootable USB. The solution was:

- *Press and hold power button till the System starts and shuts down, then press again and the motherboard starts recovery mode*

Now, I can boot into the UEFI firmware settings and Windows, but POST, the Gigabyte logo screen, booting, etc. takes a scarily long duration, as if the UEFI firmware is struggling. UEFI firmware version is F6 from 2013, installed Windows is 32bit, and I cannot install 64bit Windows 10, giving two msgs:

- Showed on a separate MBR partitioned storage device:

  ```
  Selected disc has MBR partition table.
  On EFI system, Windows can only be installed on a GPT disk
  ```
- Showed while attempting fresh install over the working 32 bit Windows installed device:

  ```
  Windows cannot be installed to this disk, this computer's hardware may not support booting to this disk.
  Ensure disk controller is enabled in the BIOS menu.
  ```

It looks like CSM [Legacy] Mode option is malfunctioning, and wants to remain UEFI only?!

- LegacyROM, Legacy first, etc. is set to Legacy, but doesn't let install on an MBR partitioned storage drive
- The only storage device (other than the one with 32bit OS) that didn't show any error msg was GPT formatted, but it didn't proceed installing since there was a good copy of already installed Windows on that storage device.

---

1. Since the installed Windows is 32 bit, should I first update the UEFI firmware with available 32bit Windows support files [App center, UEFI firmware, .NET Framework, LAN driver, etc.] from the Gigabyte Support webpage, then install a newer 64bit Windows?
2. Should I install a 64bit Windows on GPT formatted storage first, then attempt the UEFI firmware update?

Comment: Yes, why do you ask?

Comment: Because of the missing paragraphs. Now, it's OK.

Comment: Right, the enter key!

Comment: What is the computer model? Note that the BIOS is a stand-alone update, the others are for Windows.

Comment: Gigabyte Z87 HD3 with i5 4570.  I was worried about the architecture complication. Now that you mentioned it,  it's clear.

Comment: @harrymc Basically your comment answered the question. The extensive description might feel unnecessary, did it that way to find if there is anything that I don't know about, one might point it out.

Comment: [CSM \[Legacy\] Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI#CSM_booting) should never be enabled unless needing to access a legacy OPROM _(the sole purpose of it was for distros that didn't yet support EFI boot circa <2017; Windows >7 supports EFI boot)_. With CSM Mode enabled, UEFI firmware [64bit] has to emulate BIOS' 16bit architecture within a 32bit environment and it causes performance loss, both for the UEFI firmware and booting an OS. To install 64bit Windows, backup data, disable CSM Mode, enable Secure Boot, and clean install Windows from an Install USB configured for EFI boot

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ When it comes to OEM drivers on systems no longer supported by the OEM, the only OEM drivers that should be used are CPU-related drivers since they're customized to the motherboard by the OEM _(e.g. CPU chipset, CPU thermal, etc.)_, GPU drivers for the GPU that came with the system _(these are also customized by the OEM for the GPU)_, and any model specific software. It's imperative CPU chipset drivers are installed immediately upon exiting OOBE _**prior to**_ connecting to the internet, running Windows Update, or installing any other drivers/software, rebooting afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Gigabyte documentation](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z87-HD3-rev-1x#ov),
your firmware is already UEFI and the computer supports Windows 10
64-bit. The latest [UEFI firmware update F8](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z87-HD3-rev-1x/support#support-dl-bios) dates from Aug 13, 2014, almost a decade ago, so might not help much, but you can check and update if your version is earlier than that.

Note that Windows 10 64-bit is best installed on a GPT disk with the UEFI firmware not in Legacy Mode but can be installed on MBR if necessary.

The UEFI firmware is a stand-alone update with the other updates intended for Windows. As they are quite old, don't install them if their components work well.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is first turn off CSM. Unless you have a specific need to run the CSM, you simply don't need it on modern hardware. In regards to installing an updated BIOS - yes always update the bios prior to OS install if possible.

Second after that is disabled, you do want to format your hard drive as GPT (which 64bit Windows installer will do automatically). The message you're getting is Windows detecting a previous install. You'll use the 'delete' option an all partitions in the list, (obviously make sure you have all the data you need off first) then press the 'format' button to recreate the correct GPT partitions.